# Error when converting string to float

Tags: python

I am having troubles writing a python script. Specifically, I have a string of numbers and want to replace the word ''zero'' with the integer 0. I then want to cover this string into float values. I used data.replace, and as such had to put "" around the 0 - if not there is an error as it expects a character buffer object. Am I right in saying that I can strip the "" from the 0 before converting to a float?

```
>  for data in inFile: 
>  data = data.replace ("zero", "0")

>  data = map(float,data.strip('"'))
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: s

It is part of a larger script, which takes in a list of values. I want to subtract the last 100 values of this list for a given line from the first 100.

```
inFile = gzip.open('path','rb')

inpNorm = 0.5
samNorm = 1

inFile.next()
for line in inFile:
        cols = line.strip().split('\t')
        data = cols[6:]
        for data in inFile:
                data = data.replace("zero",0)
        data = map(float,data.strip('"'))

        inputVals = [x * inpNorm for x in data[:100]]
        h3k27Vals = [x * samNorm for x in data[100:]]

        normVals = [h327Vals[i] - inputVals[i] for i in len(inputVals)]

        print '\t'.join(cols[:6]) + '\t'.join(map(str,normVals))

inFile.close()
```

My input file looks like the following:

```
C8098283        1       8268    asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.00001  .       +  zero    zero    zero    11.701  12.801   13.91
```

Many thanks

P.S. Really sorry if this is not explicit enough. Im very new to programming and stack overflow.

Comment: show an example input

Comment: Seems like you have stray characters in you data file.

Comment: Can you be more clear on the conversion? You need to not strip `"`

Comment: Can you print *data* and tell us what's the value of *data* after `data = data.replace ("zero", "0")`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: edited above. thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions.

```
line = "8268    asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.00001  .       +  zero    zero    zero    11.701  12.801   13.91"
print("Input: '{}'".format(line))

converted_line = "0".join(line.split('zero')) # Split the line where you have 'zero' and rebuild the string with '0'
print("Converted line: '{}'".format(converted_line))
```

You said you wanted to convert the values. There's a couple of non-float entries in the line, but the last 6 values seems to be interesting. I usually unpack values by:

```
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6 = map(float, converted_line.rstrip().split()[4:])
# .split() with no argument splits on whitespace
# .rstrip() is to remove trailing '\n' (newlines), which are common when parsing files
print("Data:", v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6)
```

Of course, you could store it in an array as well (i.e. `data = map(float, converted ...)`). Running it all together yields the output

```
Input: '8268    asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.00001  .       +  zero    zero    zero    11.701  12.801   13.91'
Converted line: '8268    asx1.1_ox1.0.loc.00001  .       +  0    0    0    11.701  12.801   13.91'
Data: 0.0 0.0 0.0 11.701 12.801 13.91
```

---

Also, to address your actual problem. Right now you want to read from different places in the file after each other (i.e. you would like to go `0 -> 100, 1 -> 101, 2 -> 102`, etc). This is a little bit cumbersome and not really that efficient. If your file size is not too big (maybe < 1M lines or something), I would instead recommend you read in the whole file, do your calculations, and then do what you want with the data. In pseudo code like

```
col1 = []
col2 = []
...

for line in file.readlines(): 
    v1, v2, ... = map(float, converted_line.rstrip().split()[...])
    col1.append(v1)
    col2.append(v2)
    ...

# Now do your data manipulation of the parsed data that you find in `col1`, `col2`, etc
```